# Is it possible to WATCH multiple Redis KEYs in python?

Tags: python, redis

I've been playing with Redis lately, wondering how to accomplish watching multiple keys at once. 
Would something like below be atomic?

Following code uses redis-py;

```
 while True:            
        try:
            pipe.watch(key)
            pipe.watch(another_key)
            pipe.multi()
            pipe.set(key, value)
            pipe.set(another_key, another_value)
            pipe.execute()

            break
        except redis.WatchError:
            continue

        finally:
            pipe.reset()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

redis has support for multiple keys, yes: http://redis.io/commands/watch

although the docs for the python client say that pipelined commands are executed atomically, I would still use a single `WATCH` call with multiple arguments:

```
pipe.watch(key, another_key)
```

Comment: Lol I've gone through the documentation at least for 5 times or so. Funny thing didn't notice the args.